Handling MySQL BIT Data Type in Knex: Conversion from Buffer to Boolean
i am using knex db with mysql in wappler low code software and i have a column in my table and column name is is_active and it have bit datatype ig it means boolean right ?
so when i use select query to return data
it should return data like
is_active : 1 or 0
or may be
is_active : true and false
but it return data like
 "is_active":  {
     "type": "Buffer",
      "data": [ 1 ]
   },

why ?

Make it easy to assist you, provide a complete [mcve]. Also show us your current query attempt. Note, use properly formatted text (not images, not links.)

My guess is that knex has a generic converter for the bit data type, which could be longer than 1 bit. This is a knex question really that you should ask from knex developers as to the why.
